# "Karma init" not initializing config file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

[image]

I have installed karma-cli -g,karma -g,karma-jasmine -dev,karma-chrome-launcher -dev. I have set all the required path variable.

"npm list karma" also returning proper version.
Still init not working as shown in the snap below. I am stuck in it since last week . Please help

Answer (score 0):

there are a number of things that you can do to fix it.
1) Make sure that your PATH variable have the Karma executable path mentioned.
2) Install karma and karma-cli to -dev as well and start karma init from within your project root directly.
3) Find Karma on your local machine. CD to that directory, launch karma init there and then copy the resulted Karma.conf.js to your desired folder. you might have to tweak it a little.